# Flutter - get coarse location to improve search results - without explicit permissions

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

So I've been developing a Flutter app, and I have a form that enables the user to choose a location from a SearchBox. This SearchBox is provided by this package https://github.com/Bernardi23/search_map_place.
It makes use of Google Maps API to provide results. It allows a location parameter to refine these results.

However, I don't want to ask the user explicitly for his location, as I don't need an exact location, but a very coarse one, simply to refine the results (if the user is from the US I don't want to show him results from Europe).

Is there a way to do this without asking explicitly for location permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a package like [`flutter_ip`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ip) and pass the result of any external IP address found to an API like https://ip-api.com.

**BUT** it might be against the acceptable use policies of both PlayStore and AppStore, if you feel you can risk it, go ahead (This is a feeling I have, it might be totally ok)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it and see if it isn't against the use policies.